# Why I'm getting 0's from array B but it's working on array A

Tags: java, arrays, subset

I'm trying to write a code to get the compliment, intersection … of 2 subsets.

It was all working good but when I got to the Union section I got something wrong and can't figure it out.

I am trying to take all `int` from array A and Array B and store them in a new array `uAB`; the code is working on copying from array A but I'm getting 0's from array B.

The `L+M-countI` is the array length from previous arrays `A, B` and their intersection, and by `iAB` I mean the array of intersection which I wrote it before and its working.

```
int ou = 0;
int countUA = 0;
int countUB = 0;
int uAB[] = new int[L + M - countI];

for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < iAB.length; k++) {
        if (A[j] == iAB[k])
            countUA++;
    }
    if (countUA == 0) {
        uAB[ou] = A[j];
        ou++;
    }
}

int ab = ou;
for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
        if (B[j] == A[k])
            countUB++;
    }
    if (countUB == 0) {
        uAB[ab] = B[j];
        ab++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spacesbetweenoperatorspleasethisisnoteasytoreadfixeditforyouthistime

Comment: Where are `A`, `B`, `L`, `M`, `countI` and `iAB` defined?

Comment: @Michael I don't know where you mean to put spaces since I already have spaces in the whole code

Comment: if you are using an IDE, please debug your code. Will give you some insights.

Comment: @SubhasishBhattacharjee im writing on Textpad, by compiling the code is error-free.

Comment: @JadElAsmar Don't do `k=0;k<A.length;k++)`, do `k = 0; k < A.length; k++)`. There are spaces now because we edited it.

Comment: I don't understand this problem yet. However, you seem to be quite new at programming, so let me suggest a different approach: try to write shorter methods. Once they work, you can start combining them.

I guess you don't want to throw away everything you wrote. It is frustrating. Really. But it happens to professional programmers too, quite often. So you can save this in a separate file, and start something from scratch again.

Also, you could post the whole code that compiles. Then we can help with this code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is wrong. You are not considering the common elements, removing them completely from the resultant, i.e union set.
You need to consider them atleast once.

```html
  int ou = 0;
  int present = 0;
  // below are my dummy values
  int[] A = new int[]{5,8,7,6,9,2,3,98};
  int[] B = new int[]{6,9,2,3,63,123};
  int[] iAB = new int[]{6,9,2,3};
  int uAB[] = new int[10];

  for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < uAB.length; k++) {
          if (A[j] == uAB[k]) // check if its already present in the union set
              present++;
      }
      if (ou < uAB.length && present == 0) {
          uAB[ou] = A[j];
          ou++;
      }
      present = 0; // reset the present flag for the next number
  }
 // System.out.println(ou);
 // int ab = ou; no need to do this as ou will point to the place for the next insertion
  for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < uAB.length; k++) {
          if (B[j] == uAB[k]) // check if its already present in the union set
              present++;
      }
      if (ou < uAB.length && present == 0) {
          uAB[ou] = B[j];
          ou++;
      }
      present = 0; // reset the present flag for the next number
  }

  for (int k = 0; k < uAB.length; k++) {

      System.out.println(uAB[k]);

  }
```

Just a thought: This is good as of now, though you can make the code more readable, by seperating the repeated steps into a function and calling when needed, like when we are checking if the number is present in the union set.

Comment: thanks mate, the problem was I didn't reset the present flag.

Comment: glad, it was of help @JadElAsmar